# when i config HBase, met a bug i can't find the clue

Tags: hbase

When I config HBase, I met this bug，I think the bug is in:

```
distMode=`$bin/hbase --config "$HBASE_CONF_DIR" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool hbase.cluster.distributed`
```

so i add `echo "alert(4)"` to the head to the hbase, but i can't find `alert(4)`.

## start-hbase.sh(Fragment)

```
echo "alert(1)"

#start hbase daemons
errCode=$?
if [ $errCode -ne 0 ]
then
  exit $errCode
fi

echo "alert(1.5)"
echo $HBASE_CONF_DIR
echo org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool
echo hbase.cluster.distributed

distMode=`$bin/hbase --config "$HBASE_CONF_DIR" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool hbase.cluster.distributed`

echo "alert(2)"
echo $distMode
```

## system print

```
bob1@master:~$ hbase-0.94.0/bin/start-hbase.sh 
START_JAVA_HOME
alert(1)
alert(1.5)
/home/bob1/hbase-0.94.0/conf
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool
hbase.cluster.distributed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1/6/0/24
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .usr.lib.jvm.java-6-sun-1.6.0.24
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24.  Program will exit.
alert(2)
```

Comment: where is your JAVA_HOME pointing to

Answer (score 1):

export HBASE_HOME=/PATH_TO_INSTALL/hbase-0.95.2-hadoop2/

before starting HBase

Answer (score 0):

Please check your /home/bob1/hbase-0.94.0/conf/hbase-env.sh file.

It has following option to set the JAVA_HOME for your HBase environment.

`# The java implementation to use.  Java 1.6 required.
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24`

Also set the JAVA_HOME in your .profile file.

Comment: I already configed the /home/bob1/hbase-0.94.0/conf/hbase-env.sh and .profile. but also not work. thanks for you replay.

Answer (score -1):

try to config your default jdk.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/java/jdk1.6.0_16/bin/java 300 //the second param is the java path of jdk you setup and want to use
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/java/jdk1.6.0_16/bin/javac 300
sudo update-alternatives --config java 
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

follow the instruction to choose a jdk as default.

Comment: JAVA_HOME is /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24, i try Shawn's method, but not ok.